# Where can I find an online list of CentOS packages and their versions?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, packages

I am looking for an online list of the standard packages available for CentOS Linux.

I know that if I had a CentOs system running, I could use yum to list packages. However, I am trying to evaluate what roadblocks we will run into, when we switch our webservers from Ubuntu to CentOS, and I don't yet have a CentOS setup.

I've searched and searched, but all I can find are explanations of how to manage packages once you actually have a CentOS system setup. Any website recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I started with [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=centos+mirror), which got me a [list of CentOS mirrors](https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/), and then picked the [first mirror](http://centos.arcticnetwork.ca/).

Here's a [list of packages for CentOS 6](http://centos.arcticnetwork.ca/6/os/x86_64/Packages/).

If the particular mirror lsited here is dead, you can simply find another mirror by returning to [the list of mirrors](https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/) and follow the same logic.

Comment: Thanks, the "mirrors" keyword was the what I couldn't sus out before.

Answer (score 5):

This mirror seems to be kept up-to-date:
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/

Answer (score 3):

See https://pkgs.org/ which allows you to search a range of CentOS (and other) distributions.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at any mirror

http://centos.mirror.nexicom.net/6/os/x86_64/Packages/